# Inserting a nested collection into Mongodb with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array I am attempting to insert into a collection type with Node.JS and Mongoose. DB Schema defined as such:

```
//LIBRARY
var LibrarySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {type:String, required: true},
    keyw: {type:String, required: true},
    data: {type:String, required: true},
    ref: {url: String}
},
 {collection: 'library'}
)
```

I have been able to successfully insert the array (which shows up as a comma-delimited list) but can't seem to master what I assume is something simple. I have read through various documentation and this SHOULD work:

```
// Dummy Data
var b.topic = "This is my name"
var b.keywords = "keyword1,keyword2,keyword3"
var data = "This is some data, just another string"
var arrRef = []
arrRef[0] = "http://www.website1.com"
arrRef[1] = "http://www.website2.com"
//Create Schema & Save
var lib = new db.Library({
    name: b.topic,
    keyw: b.keywords,
    data: b.data,
    ref: {$addToSet: {url: arrRef}}
})
lib.save(function(err,docs) {
    console.log("Error:" + err)
}
```

What I'm trying to have in the data is:

```
name: "This is my name"
keyw: "keyword1,keyword2,keyword3"
data: "This is some data, just another string"
ref:
      url: "http://www.website1.com"
      url: "http://www.website2.com"
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? The code above does not populate the "ref" field whatsoever.

Comment: May help: `ref: {url: String}` should be `ref: [{url: String}]`.

Comment: I've tried that, but it only creates a blank array

Comment: Oh -- try `lib.ref.addToSet()` as `$addToSet` was removed in the 3.0+ branch ([docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/migration.html)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment above by @WiredPrairie shows, `ref` should be an array, not an object like you have it defined in your schema. However, since `ref` is a simply collection of urls (strings), each one does not need the `url` property, and therefore does not need to be an object.

Also, you might find that making `keyw` an array will work better for you, because it will be easier to find documents based on keywords using the [$in operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/in/).

Try this schema:

```
{
    name: {type:String, required: true},
    keyw: {type:Array, required: true},
    data: {type:String, required: true},
    ref: []
}
```

And this code

```
var lib = new db.Library({
    name: b.topic,
    keyw: b.keywords.split(','),
    data: b.data,
    ref: arrRef
})
```

Since this is a **new** document, you don't need `$addToSet`. Use that operator when **updating**.

Comment: Thank you -- this is what I was after, I just didn't understand the correct syntax!